# File upload rest service using Mule Error

Tags: rest, jersey, mule

I have created a File upload rest service using Mule and jersey according to this [post](http://www.javaroots.com/2013/05/createfileuploadmulejerseyrest.html). Everything is working fine, but the problem with this is that somehow mule is not releasing the lock on the file which is getting uploaded on server side. So you can not move or delete the file while mule server is running. How can I remove this restriction ?

Comment: The `FileUploadService` shown in this blog doesn't use Mule's file transport so the lock you're experiencing has to come from something else. Do you get the `200 File uploaded to : ...` response in the HTTP client performing the upload?

Comment: i am not using mule's file transport ..i am just getting input stream from rest service and write it to server's end . I have closed all the  streams before returning output , and yes , i am getting 200 File uploaded to response . File is also getting uploaded , but the lock is not released . when i close the mule application , then only i can access the uploaded file

Answer (score 0):

From what you're saying in the comments and looking at the source code of the blog post you mention, I reckon the problem lies here:

```
finally{
  if(out !=null)
    try {
     uploadedInputStream.close();
     out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My impression is that `uploadedInputStream.close()` fails and `out.close()` never gets released. Closing `uploadedInputStream` is useless here so I suggest you remove the line and see if the lock gets removed.

Comment: David ..you are right ..the problem in this code only ...i tried with apache commons IO ...and its working great ...thanks for your prompt help and answers :)

Comment: but still why the existing code is not working ..even if i put out.close() first , there were no exceptions though ...

Comment: Using Commons IO is best, I wasn't sure it was OK for you. But maybe with the raw code above, you don't see the exception because stderr is captured and not sent to the console? Have you tried step debugging this code?

Comment: i did debug it multiple times ..but it never went to exception block ..anyways thanks for your answer